# Persisting collections of hierarchical data with good performance

Tags: java, sql, database, performance, persistence

In my particular case I'm working with java, jdbcTemplate and HSQLDB database, but I think this can be viewed as a generic question about database persistence.

Lets say I have a collection of People. Each person can be a parent to other people, and a child to other people. Let say each person can have multiple addresses, and multiple attributes such as height, weight and eye colour.

So we have the following tables.

Person

Address (with a reference back to person table)

Attributes (with a reference back to person table)

Relationship (with two references back to person table, one for parent, one for child)

And lets say I have a large collection of persons that needs to be persisted in my application.

What are the good patterns for persisting this data with good performance?

Obviously persisting each person one at a time would be slow.

The next option to is to collect up all the persons, all their addresses, attributes and relationships into their own separate collections and persist those in batches.

However, this is where I am stuck at the moment.

I am using Database generated sequence Ids.

If I persist all of the persons in a batch first, how do I get the persons IDs to persist all of the address, attributes and relationships for those persons?

Should I switch to generating the IDs in my application code, if so, what are the best practices?

Or should I perhaps somehow reference the required persons using a different key that's known in the application code. Like the person's name + surname columns...

Are there other methods?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are planning to do things is unworkable.

You appear to be somewhat coupled to a database, since you have the database issue your ids, but you also appear to have all your data in memory and to somehow need to persist everything to the database in one go.  These two modes of operation are incompatible with each other.

The way this is normally done is either by fully integrating with the database, or by not using a database at all.

- To fully integrate with the database means to use an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) framework like Hibernate, possibly via JPA.  You really should read up on those two.  This way, you do not keep all of your data in memory, so there is no performance concern of how to persist some huge chunk of data at once.
- To not use a database at all, stream all your data into an XML file before your application closes, and stream your data from the same XML file when your application starts up.  Read up on JAXB on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. 1)Believe it or not I started solving my problem with Hibernate at first, but then got frustrated and gave up due to wanting more granular control as well as lack of understanding on my part, and I will definitely look into using it again with a bit more reading done before hand. 2) File based persistence will not be effective for me, besides I'd prefer JSON :P 3) Why do you say it's unworkable? Wouldn't Hibernate be solving the problem I described behind the scenes anyway? How does Hibernate solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Database generated sequence Ids.

When using multiple servers, you need the DB (or some complicated distributed synchronization) for the IDs. Still, you can get the ID from the DB and assign it manually. In order to do this efficiently, you can use hi-lo algorithm (or better: [pooled](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/)).

> If I persist all of the persons in a batch first, how do I get the persons IDs to persist all of the address, attributes and relationships for those persons?

No idea, how this can be done. It's surely possible as Hibernate can do it. Assigning the IDs yourself could be simpler.

> Or should I perhaps somehow reference the required persons using a different key that's known in the application code. Like the person's name + surname columns...

This can get complicated and may not work. Cases when the first and last name aren't unique are pretty common.